# Dynamic summarize without column name

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How can you construct a summarize statement dynamically based on a string array of columns ?

```
deviceTelemetry 
| summarize <FOR-EACH-COLUMNS>avg(column)<FOR-EACH-COLUMNS> by deviceId
```

EDIT

Here is a dataset, "keys" contains columns names I would like to use in the summary aggregation, "deviceTelemetry" the expected result (In this case, columns are hardcoded).

```
let deviceTelemetry = datatable (deviceId:guid, timestamp:datetime, value:dynamic)[
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  60}),
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  50}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level": 100, "flow": 350}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  90, "flow": 360}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 19:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  80, "flow": 370}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  70, "flow": 380}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  120}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  130}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  140}),
];
let keys = deviceTelemetry
| summarize make_bag(value)
| extend keys=bag_keys(bag_value)
| mv-expand keys
| distinct tostring(keys);
keys;
let flowColumnName = "flow";
let levelColumnName = "level";
let pressureColumnName = "pressure";
deviceTelemetry
| evaluate  bag_unpack(value)
| summarize
            level=avg(toreal(column_ifexists(levelColumnName, levelColumnName))), 
            flow=avg(toreal(column_ifexists(flowColumnName, flowColumnName))),
            pressure=avg(toreal(column_ifexists(pressureColumnName, pressureColumnName)))
            by timestamp=bin(timestamp , 1d) , deviceId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin

```
let deviceTelemetry = datatable (deviceId:guid, timestamp:datetime, value:dynamic)[
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  60}),
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  50}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level": 100, "flow": 350}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  90, "flow": 360}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 19:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  80, "flow": 370}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  70, "flow": 380}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  120}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  130}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  140}),
];
deviceTelemetry
| mv-expand kind=array value
| extend k = tostring(value[0]), v = toreal(value[1])
| extend timestamp_bin = bin(timestamp , 1d)
| evaluate pivot(k, avg(v),  timestamp_bin, deviceId)
```

| timestamp_bin | deviceId | flow | level | pressure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf | NaN | 55 | NaN |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092 | 365 | 85 | NaN |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895 | NaN | NaN | 130 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA73UzWrjMBAA4Hsg7zDkEhukRZItS3bpA%20x9byUs%20hkXU9sJjuI27O67r9x4S9pDCS6sDAbNSPMxB02LATyOjcMf2GKHYTjDPXgT4mdbhOSS/O6rx1PjCYSmw2Mw3aGKZ3DaERhNe8LKn3vTNS59WK%202tfc1d%20goL7yleV5wWjKpaOaZxrywhXX1lmwFE4wySbkErirGq0x%20U0qyuLYE5oLJL9i0OGK7qQAK9iclywB9EyBnwMyL1uhz6kQWFSEsRS2RaaUcK8WSDjhjBDZ1u3%20Om%20wL2m3tlNdasVwrb9L0taYWa4LdpKlrTc%20asyx3rq5prq2jOWealp4XVHnlbcml0KX8oPHPtMOAx%20NpwAnkYjnyaUvvkOx/dJJfkN3devXh9a9Xv6EbKb4cTO/hqen9vRkGc7688imLLwGnVJwTYX8MQ9M/Jq/JB7ZL4zR4jQ9o2jnKd%20nVtbcB8tM2fTwa/8lbDAhwfzk93Y0TBg7NuA/JEwEzRibWf1%20BwL8Blf4FkG8uh8sEAAA=)

Comment: To get back to dynamic without Nan --->  | extend packAll=pack_all()
| extend packWithNan=bag_remove_keys(packAll, dynamic(['deviceId', 'timestamp_bin']))
| project-away packAll
| mv-expand kind=array packWithNan
| where packWithNan[1] != 'NaN'
| extend packWithoutNan=pack(tostring(packWithNan[0]), packWithNan[1])
| summarize value=make_bag(packWithoutNan) by deviceId, timestamp_bin

Comment: @draco951, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: The goal is to do an average aggregation of telemetry (Without knowing the properties), this is what you have achieved with your superb query. folowing that, I want to get those 3 columns (flow, level, pressure) in a dynamic form without the "NaN" value.  EXAMPLE:
{
  "level": 55.0
}
{
  "flow": 365.0,
  "level": 85.0
}
{
  "pressure": 130.0
}

Comment: Well, there other solutions :-) Want to post a new question for that?

Comment: Thank for your help ! Sure --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73413248/how-to-merge-dynamic-number-data-with-condition