# How to merge dynamic number data with condition?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Let take the following dataset

| timestamp_bin | deviceId | flow | level | pressure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf | NaN | 55 | NaN |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092 | 365 | 85 | NaN |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895 | NaN | NaN | 130 |

I would like to merge the flow, level and pressure column **without the NaN** values and **without having to mention the flow, level and pressure column**:

| deviceId | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf | 2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000 | {"level": 55.0} |
| aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092 | 2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000 | {"flow": 365.0, "level": 85.0} |
| cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895 | 2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000 | {"pressure": 130.0} |

The following query allow to achieve this result

```
let deviceTelemetry = datatable (deviceId: guid, timestamp: datetime, flow: real, level: real, pressure: real)
[
    'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf', '2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', real(NaN),        55, real(NaN),
    'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092', '2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000',       365,        85, real(NaN),
    'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895', '2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', real(NaN), real(NaN),       130,
];
deviceTelemetry
| extend packAll=pack_all()
| extend packWithNan=bag_remove_keys(packAll, dynamic(['deviceId', 'timestamp']))
| project-away packAll
| mv-expand kind=array packWithNan
| where packWithNan[1] != 'NaN'
| extend packWithoutNan=pack(tostring(packWithNan[0]), packWithNan[1])
| summarize value=make_bag(packWithoutNan) by deviceId, timestamp
```

Is there a better way to achieve this query ?

Edit:

This discussion is a continuation of this previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389950/dynamic-summarize-without-column-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... and just for the fun of it, here is an extension of the previous solution:

```
let deviceTelemetry = datatable (deviceId:guid, timestamp:datetime, value:dynamic)[
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  60}),
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  50}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level": 100, "flow": 350}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  90, "flow": 360}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 19:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  80, "flow": 370}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  70, "flow": 380}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  120}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  130}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  140}),
];
deviceTelemetry
| mv-expand kind=array value
| extend k = tostring(value[0]), v = toreal(value[1])
| extend timestamp_bin = bin(timestamp , 1d)
| evaluate pivot(k, avg(v), timestamp_bin, deviceId)
// add the following 2 lines of code
| mv-apply with_itemindex=i pa = pack_all() on (summarize make_bag_if(pa, i >= 2 and tostring(pa) !has_cs "NaN"))
| project timestamp_bin, deviceId, bag_pa
```

| timestamp_bin | deviceId | bag_pa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf | {"level":55} |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092 | {"flow":365,"level":85} |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895 | {"pressure":130} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA72US4vbMBDH74F8h2kusUHqSo7fJb33sqfelsXI0jhRIz%20wHW/Sx3evnLghu9AlpFAJDJrXb/7CGoM9KBy0xK9osMS%20PcIalOjtzg2Cc3Z%20UelmrxWBXpfY9aJsUhuD44nAIMweU3WsRKml%20zSfLQulCi5RUh6qnPp%20yGnCgoiuFIvRD/Mwl8WSLD3mMcoCygPgUcp4ugo%20RlHA7FoSmAo6P2BhcECzSAFC9ssl9wHimwDBBBDTogUqn0pvZSmel1OMA2RxFEmWePco4IwRWBSmfrGH1T/QbpOTXNPC%202nJTbT4mhbdTfPYTbTomhZPNJkzX8qioH6cS%20pzFtNE8ZBGKlJ5wgMvToI3NP4erWmx6/YtjkDu3Q95V9IryOp/KPHPkOdP89mb1z%20f/YRyoHhoRKVgpyu1Fm0rjudXPnrx0OPosnOir7u%201dXGOTmf2LNrp8HJ3qIwk5U/u1dplwGS5bqyofbrXGxAgKtz9JhrJww0eqh7Z0dADBbjktcFCPyZTzbr4QGEsoQtQlEb%202PYzsADoyvsoC5A1goneaJpzBFedL/NdI%20lVYmHtYZG2I4aIXeZMMZxoa7A6fZlKVr9HaEUO8xyscl04TSCgIbPa1t/vKfLRTTChQ9b0WWyg8WjeFy4JzlNW39D2f%20teQJj2Ub8BgqKh92OBQAA)

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's important to share the whole scenario and not just a friction of it :-)

```
let deviceTelemetry = datatable (deviceId:guid, timestamp:datetime, value:dynamic)[
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  60}),
'fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  50}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 17:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level": 100, "flow": 350}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 18:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  90, "flow": 360}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 19:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  80, "flow": 370}),
'aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "level":  70, "flow": 380}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  120}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 20:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  130}),
'cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895','2020-05-15 21:01:35.7750000', dynamic({ "pressure":  140}),
];
deviceTelemetry
| mv-expand kind=array value
| extend k = tostring(value[0]), v = toreal(value[1])
| summarize avg(v) by k, timestamp_bin = bin(timestamp , 1d), deviceId
| summarize make_bag(pack_dictionary(k, avg_v)) by timestamp_bin, deviceId
```

| timestamp_bin | deviceId | bag_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | fddf1cec-16db-4461-9057-3d08e46b6bcf | {"level":55} |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | aaaaaaaa-fed4-c23b-422b-e85e0877c092 | {"level":85,"flow":365} |
| 2020-05-15T00:00:00Z | cb04ccff-48bc-4108-9d16-7d7db9152895 | {"pressure":130} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA73UzWrjMBAA4Hsg7zDkEhusIsk/sl36AHvfWwlBP%20MgYjvBdtx6t333lRPvbtJDCS5UAoM0nvmYg6bEDgz2VuNPLLHCrhngCYzs3FYlgncJ/jD57mRNAJ2tsO1kdczdPzieAuhlecLcDLWsrPafl4t1YUzBNGrCEqNIFCWMZDQWJDQ0xShRidLFOlhzyimhMWExMJFTlofxgxAxdWsdwFTQ%20w2rEnssVzlAQt/9YB6Q3gXEEyCnRQo0EdE8dArnimAaI02F0DTjczpglAawKsrDizuEX9Duaye71pL5WnaXll5rYrbG6V2auNbSSdOKRloXBYlSpUnEaEoywxIijDAqYzFPs/iDxj7Tjg227anBEWR8PvJpSzdI%20B2dRBdk87hcfHj9y8UbVD3B16OsDextbZ5k08jh8srHKL52OIbcnOgObdfYeuedg89047tpcL5vUJbTLdv4Y1p7qirZ2F8IsncJPqgB9lcDZats7VLd1/t3BwEw42r%20HUK3dSq5x62SO%208o9X5rrO7soZbN4Lmyztj2/hm5Ef7X%20gOX6S22%20gQAAA==)

Comment: Your queries are just superb ! Do you have any suggestions on exercice material to train on kusto queries ? :-)

Comment: :-) Simply use the documentation. Make sure that you understand and know how to use the basic operators and go over the list of functions